# A back door power window on a 2012 Subaru Forester not rolling up

Tags: subaru, fuse, power-windows, forester

On our 2012 Subaru Forester, the back window doesn't roll up anymore. Neither the button on the driver's control switch, nor on the door itself has any effect. There's no response to the button and we don't hear the motor. All other windows are working properly. (Nevertheless, I checked the fuse and it's fine. There isn't a fuse specific to each window, is there?)

What's the next thing to try?

Comment: pull the door panel and try jumping the motor directly. more than likely you'll need a new window motor.

Comment: I was hoping to hear that I would nee to replace the control switch. Why is *that* not the case?

Comment: it could be the switch, test for power on the green/black wire at the switch then test either the blue or red wire for power when the switch is in either position. jumping the motor would tell you wether or not it's a wiring/switch or motor issue. on the subarus there is. 30a circuit breaker and a 30a fuse that powers all the switches.

Answer (score 3):

Hold up, don't order a motor just yet. What Ben meant (assuming) was pull the panel and jump the motor to *test* whether the motor is still working.

If it's not the motor, you can unplug the switch from the regulator and use wires to jump into the regulator plug (try to find a diagram, or be confident about which pin is ground)... finally, if that rolls the window up, you know it's the switch.

Comment: Is it a clue that neither the driver's nor the back switch work? Does that suggest a motor problem? Or are the two switches in series somehow; and one switch not working would mean the other can't function either?

Comment: @Lem.ma when you say neither switch works do you mean the master switch doesn't work for any window or that it doesn't work for just the single window? the rear sub switches pull ground from the master switch and have a common splice for power.